# Procedural Wire Generator in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, procedural, splines

I’d like to figure out the method to creating this procedural wire generator inside Animation Nodes 2.1 as depicted in this youtube video here:

https://youtu.be/lsXb5ywrg_I

The video gives little indication of how to setup the loop, ive mostly been guessing up to this point, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BziV080OFHQ&t=664s this and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEYI4lnOprY might be helpful starting points